# Python get value from Geojson

Tags: python, json, geojson

Please can someone share some python script that will loop through this geojson and retrieve the values under "attachment". I am struggling with these ones.

Thank you

```
{
 "id": 3,
 "geom": "POINT (-65621.7187500000000000 6688807.5000000000000000)",
 "fields": {
  "Identifier": null,
  "Species": null,
  "Tag_Number": "Quercus robur 505",
},
"extensions": {
"description": null,
"attachment": [
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "1531402833735.jpg",
    "size": 4559151,
    "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
    "description": "",
    "is_image": true
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "1531402882838.jpg",
    "size": 6418150,
    "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
    "description": "",
    "is_image": true
  }
]
}
}
```

Comment: The python JSON package easily turns JSON into a dict. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

The sample json you provided does not look like valid [geojson](http://geojson.org/) to me.  You can find parsers that are not as strict, but the comma (",") at the end of the "Tag_Number" line for example should not be there, and I'd expect to find a "type" attribute defining any geometry or features.

That aside, geojson adds semantic meaning for json so you can for the purposes of your task can treat it as any json parsing task in Python.

If your data is in a file `sample.geojson` you can read from a file with the `load()` method:

```
import json

with open('sample.geojson') as data:
    geo = json.load(data)
```

This results in `geo` being a regular [Python Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) that you can inspect.  By calling `geo.keys()` you can find all of the keys in the data.

```
In [4]: geo.keys()
Out[4]: [u'fields', u'geom', u'extensions', u'id']
```

You access any of the values as you would any Python dictionary by specifying a key: `geo['extensions']`.

```
In [5]: geo['extensions']
Out[5]:
{u'attachment': [{u'description': u'',
   u'id': 7,
   u'is_image': True,
   u'mime_type': u'image/jpeg',
   u'name': u'1531402833735.jpg',
   u'size': 4559151},
  {u'description': u'',
   u'id': 8,
   u'is_image': True,
   u'mime_type': u'image/jpeg',
   u'name': u'1531402882838.jpg',
   u'size': 6418150}],
 u'description': None}
```

Since, the `extensions` is itself a dictionary you can reference it as well and loop over any of the values which happens to be a list of dictionaries.

```
In [6]: for item in geo['extensions']['attachment']:
    ...:     print(item['name'])
    ...:
1531402833735.jpg
1531402882838.jpg
```

You may find [ipython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) a useful interactive tool as you learn to work with data and data structures in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code

```
 import geojson
 gj = geojson.loads(jsonstr)
 if "attachment" in gj:
     for attachment in gj["attachment"]:
        print (attachment)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried this but it didn't return anything. I get a response if i change "attachment" to "extensions". It is like it cant look inside that....